# How can I make thumbnails a display different size/position if the blog post was posted before a specific date?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I would like to be able to display the blog post's thumbnail a smaller size and right floated if it was posted before April 11, 2019 but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is what I tried:

```
<?php
            global $post;
            $compare_date = strtotime( "2018-03-01" );
            $post_date    = strtotime( $post->post_date );

            if (has_post_thumbnail() && ( $compare_date < $post_date ) ) {
                echo '<div style="float:right;padding-left:20px;"><img src="'.the_post_thumbnail().'"  /></div>';}
            else {
                     echo '<img src="'.the_post_thumbnail().'" />';}
?>
```

But when I did this, it affected all of my post thumbnails rather than just the ones before a specific date.

Any ideas?

Comment: reverse the comparison; and use `get_the_post_thumbnail()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/ in the string concatenation, and remove the image tags because the function returns the complete image tag for the featured image.

Answer (score -1):

In what way is it affecting your post thumbnails?

I cleaned up your code a bit. If you can show me the output you're getting I'll be able to help you further.

```
<?php
    global $post;

    $compare_date = strtotime( "2018-03-01" );
    $post_date    = strtotime( $post->post_date );

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        if ( $compare_date < $post_date ) {
            echo '<div style="float:right;padding-left:20px;"><img src="' . the_post_thumbnail() . '"/></div>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<img src="' . the_post_thumbnail() . '" />';
        }
    }
?>
```